# Deleting shards folder in couched

Tags: couchdb

I am running out of space in my couchdb Server hosted on AWS. I see that shards folder is taking around 3gb of my space. Is it safe to delete the shards folder? 
If no what are other alternatives of making more free space available?? Pl help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shards folder is where you databases' shards are stored, so it's absolutely not safe to delete. Run a compaction on your biggest databases to reclaim space by calling `POST /{db}/_compact` with admin credentials ([database compaction documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/maintenance/compaction.html#database-compaction)

You might want to consider to turn on a [compaction daemon](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/compaction.html#compaction-daemon-rules) on your server to avoid this issue in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The compaction thing helped me get around the space problem..

Comment: Hi, is there anyway i can delete historical shard files?